# Debian/Apache Server waiting time very slow only with Chrome

Tags: apache-2.2, lamp, google-chrome, time-wait

I have a website running on a Linux Debian Squeeze server with Apache 2. The website is the only one on the server and the traffic to the website is very low (800-1000 connection per day).

The problem is that when I run the website on Chrome the "Wait" time is very long (1 min, 2 min) before the page is loaded. It happens just sometimes, let's say 3 pages out of 5 are slow, and it's not that certain pages are always slow: the same page could sometimes be fast, some other times slow.

The fact is that I have NO problems on any other browser (Opera, FF, IE, Safari) and the website runs perfectly on local server. So, I don't think it's a programming issue or a database/query issue.

I don't really can figure out how to understand the problem: there is absolutely NO trace on any system log that could suggest a path to find the reason of this problem.

What could I do to do a proper problem determination?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we have to know who is the problem: server or browser. 
Compare speed of `Chrome` with `curl http://site`. Also take a look on `curl -I http://site`

In case of problem side is a `Chrome` - try pressing `F12` key, and switch to `Network` tab to detect what is going on when u opening site.